# In OTRS, how can ConfigItems be found using Webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, otrs

I am building a website which is supposed to read ConfigItems of an OTRS system for maintenance purposes. So far I can find and use ConfigItems using the Webservice ConfigItem::ConfigItemGet and ConfigItem::ConfigItemSearch.

Sadly I am unable to find the option able to get all ConfigItems linked to a specific one. Is there an existing interface to query linked items or do I have to implement a new one?

Querys are sent from my angularjs website to a nodejs server which prepares the JSONs to interact with the OTRS 4.0.7 Rest interface. I don't need to change item in OTRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no web service available that returns the linked objects (either tickets or other CI's). It would be able to add this to `Kernel/GenericInterface/Operation/ConfigItem/ConfigItemGet.pm` but it's not there out of the box.

Comment: I made a new LinkList.pm using the description given in the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675372/how-to-link-get-config-item-to-an-ticket-through-webservice-soap-or-rest-in